# Showing a finite field isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Suppose $p$ is a prime number, with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, I need to prove that then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. What I have so far: 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p) \cong (\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1))/(p) \cong 
\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1,p) \cong \mathbb{F}_5[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}. 
$$
But where do we use the fact that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$? Am I on the right track?

Comment: If $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ , $-1$ is already a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: You need to show (know) that $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_p$. That's where you need the assumption $p\equiv3\pmod4$. But that step has been done on our site very many times.

Comment: Thanks, what is the reference to where that is explained?

Comment: The best reference depends on how much you know. If you have covered Legendre symbol and Euler's criterion, then you can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2255068/11619).

Comment: Nothing like that I have covered. Only basic algebra rings and fields.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339292/11619) is another approach. Using Wilson's theorem to show the existence of a zero when $p\equiv1\pmod4$. Sorry, this doesn't really help you.

Comment: But, you can use the fact that the multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ has order $p-1$. By basic group theory (Lagrange's theorem) there cannot be elements of order $4$ in that group unless $4\mid p-1$. And a zero of $x^2+1$ has order four (when $p>2$).

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\equiv 3\mod 4$,  $-1$ is *not* a quadratic residue modulo $p$, hence $X^2+1$ remains irreducible in $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Actually it is a basic theorem in *Algebraic Number Theory* that, if $p$ is an odd prime, $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod. $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\mod 4$. Its proof relies on *Euler's criterion*:

> If $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ an integer coprime to $p$, then
>
> - If $a$ is a quadratic residue mod. $p$, $\;a^{\tfrac{p-1}2}\equiv 1\mod p$.
> - If $a$ is a non-quadratic residue mod. $p$, $\;a^{\tfrac{p-1}2}\equiv -1\mod p$.

Comment: How to prove that $X^2+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ given that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, I don't see this.

Comment: @Sigurd: I've added the result which is used in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to show that $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (try it, without looking at [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741987/62967)).

Then $(p)$ is a prime, hence maximal, ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(p)$ is a field. Its elements are of the form
$$
a+bi
$$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.